# Weird difference in while statement (Bash vs sh)

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I'm learning shell scripting (more focused on sh shell than Bash shell) and I wrote a simple script testing the while statement in *sh* shell.

But when I run it I get this error...

```
test.sh: 8: test.sh: 10: not found
10
```

**But when I executed the script with bash it runned without problems (even with the `#!/bin/sh` on the script). Can someone explain why? Is the while statement different on both shells?**

*A few notes:*

1. Discovered the "solution" to run the script by debugging the script:

   ```
   bash -x test.sh
   ```
2. Permissions are `rwx` for my user and `r` for all the other users.
3. Changed the `#!/bin/sh` to `/bash` but nothing really changed (still running it with sh, was pretty dumb I know, but sometimes stupid things work).
4. The code is pretty straightforward and simple, it's just a variable and a while statement with a echo for the variable so I guess there are not syntax errors (since it runs in Bash shell).
5. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (x86_64).
6. The directory where the script is located is included on the `$PATH`.
7. Tried with `sudo` but same thing, works on *Bash*, fails on *sh*.

EDIT:

```
#!/bin/sh

var=10
while [ $var -gt 0 ]
do
        echo $var
        var=$[ $var - 1 ]
done
```

Comment: @IMN01 `$[` is a Bash thing (correct me if I’m wrong).

Comment: @Biffen Can't really correct you because I don't know much, but it looks like it is :D

Comment: I recommend you use `shellcheck` on your scripts: it reports `52055888.sh:7:13: warning: In POSIX sh, $[..] in place of $((..)) is undefined. [SC2039]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote this [bug-bash discussion](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2012-04/msg00034.html) with the maintainer of `bash` on the `$[...]` syntax:

> It dates from Posix circa 1990 (1003.2d9, of which I've lost my paper
>   copy).  I implemented it after the Berkeley guys, mostly Marc
>   Teitelbaum, put it into Posix.  It ended up getting dropped in favor
>   of the ksh `$((...))` expansion, at which point everyone deprecated the
>   old `$[...]`.  I removed it from the manual sometime later, but it still
>   works as it always has.

---

`$[...]` is a deprecated syntax that still works in `bash` but doesn't work in `dash` (that's where `/bin/sh` points to on your system, according to comments).

`dash` (being POSIX-compliant) supports the `$((...))` syntax instead:

```
var=10
while [ "$var" -gt 0 ]; do
   echo "$var"
   var=$((var-1))
done
```

Comment: Just changed my code with that modifications and it work as expected. After all, it kinda was a syntax error. Thanks for clarifying this mess :D

Comment: Great find! I once tried to figure out where `$[...]` came from and why it's still working, but not mentioned in the man page – now I know :)

Answer (score -1):

NOTE that, `#!/bin/sh` works only when you execute the script with `./test.sh` while you have the permission of `x` (execution) to the script.

Further, `bash test.sh` means you called bash, and bash reads the lines of test.sh, then execute them in the subprocess of bash, `#!/bin/sh` at the top is to be ignored as a comment.

Thus you should execute with `./test.sh`, before that you should `chmod 755 test.sh` to ensure you have the permission to execute like that.

Then, show us the code please...

**Update**
(Please read the comments) `/bin/sh` might just link the actual shell you are using. Call `readlink -f /bin/sh` to find out which shell it (currently) points to.

Comment: Also note that `/bin/sh` is often a link to `bash` or some other shell.

Comment: I just want to remind him or her the way of execution is important, and it would decide which shell is really working on the execution. T_T then I got a "-1"

Comment: Ok now I understand why running with bash or sh has different output. And already changed the permissions but same thing happens on sh test.sh or ./test.sh

Comment: @IMN01 Heh, as I said, `sh` might be linked to another shell, such as `bash` or `dash`. Try using this command `readlink -f /bin/sh`.

Comment: @PesaThe I get the following output: /bin/dash

Comment: ok, I see, thank you all. I was just trying to explain why we need the test code shown, and the answer of `even with the #!/bin/sh on the script`. ^_^